# Search Password Change Logs for Specific User?

Tags: terminal, security, password, search

Is there any way to check all password change logs for one specific user?

Someone changed my user password and I could get my user back through the appleID and terminal password reset using safe mode.

I want to prove that someone changed my password, while the mac was unlocked.

I tried to use the command `dscl . read /Users/<username> accountPolicyData`, but with it I could only find the last time it was updated - which coincides with my `resetpassword` command execution through the terminal.

I want to check if there is any place where I can see all password changes for a user

Comment: A password change either requires knowledge of the current password or admin access (in the second case your Keychain may still require the old one afterwards). Assuming you didn't share your previous password with anyone: who has admin access to your Mac?

Comment: @nohillside I don't think anyone has my password or admin access - that's why I want to know when and how my password changed. I use the same password for a year and today it didn't logged me in.

That's why I'm concern and want ot find a log file showing that the password was changed and when.

Do you think it's possible to have this password changed, without the old one, if I let my mac unlocked?

Comment: All the commands I'm aware of require either the old password or admin access.